# Cannot Delpoy Sveltekit app with Supabase From netlify

Tags: svelte, netlify, vercel, sveltekit, supabase

So i have a app with Sveltekit tailwindcss skeleton ui and supabase, i have tried to deploy from vercel and netlify but neither of them have been working!

Error:

```
import {
7:49:34 AM: 3:   PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
7:49:34 AM: 4:   PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
7:49:34 AM:      ^
7:49:34 AM: 5: } from "$env/static/public"
7:49:34 AM: error during build:
7:49:34 AM: RollupError: "PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL" is not exported by "$env/static/public", imported by "src/lib/supabase.ts".
7:49:34 AM:     at error (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:2001:30)
7:49:34 AM:     at Module.error (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12982:16)
7:49:34 AM:     at Module.traceVariable (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:13348:29)
7:49:34 AM:     at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:11847:39)
7:49:34 AM:     at Identifier.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:7807:40)
7:49:34 AM:     at CallExpression.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5598:28)
7:49:34 AM:     at CallExpression.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:9324:15)
7:49:34 AM:     at VariableDeclarator.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5602:23)
7:49:34 AM:     at VariableDeclaration.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5598:28)
7:49:34 AM:     at ExportNamedDeclaration.bind (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.7.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:10071:27)
7:49:34 AM:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1. (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
```

The error is that PUBLIC_SUPABSE_URL is not exported by $env/static/public but in VSCode there is no error that says that and my authentication with supabase is working just fine so How do i fix this??

Supbase.ts:

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit"
import {
    PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
} from "$env/static/public"

export const supabaseClient = createClient(
    PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
)
```

Comment: You need to add these keys into Netlify.